# How to send formatted input within JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, rest

Is it possible to send formatted input (like Python, C++ code) as JSON for making API requests? In one of my projects, I need to send user-written code to the backend for evaluation. What I want would be something like this theoretically (this is an invalid JSON example, but I am just trying to give an idea):

```
{
  "user_id": 1,
  "language": "python",
  "code": """
  import os
  
  for i in range(1, 10):
    print(i)
  
  """
}
```

So yes, it would be multiline and the format should be preserved. While things like newline escaping with `\n` can be added, but that wouldn't work for programming languages like Python as indentation is important here.

Is it a possible thing to do? If so, how?

Comment: Why not just write it to a file and then send the file?

Comment: You could base64 encode the code.

Comment: "that wouldn't work for programming languages like Python as indentation is important here" actually it would... As in a normal text file, you can very easily encode the indent with spaces or tabs (`\t`) in the quoted code `"this is not indented\n    but this is\n\tand so is this"`